# Niginx Server: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Tags: http, ssl, nginx, https

I recently hosted a react app on EC2 with nginx. The react app is running on port 3000.

So I redirected HTTP & HTTPS requests to port 3000 using -

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000

sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000

sudo service netfilter-persistent save
```

I have added the domain name and certificate details in the conf file in /etc/nginx/sites-available. The conf file is -

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   root /var/www/myapp/client/build;
   server_name example.com;
   index index.html index.htm;
   ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/bundle.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/mykey.key;

   location / {
   }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com ip_address;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

When I run this -

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n
```

I get this-

```
COMMAND    PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-n  630 systemd-network   19u  IPv4  25765      0t0  UDP 172.11.25.109:68 
systemd-r  641 systemd-resolve   12u  IPv4  15768      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.53:53 
systemd-r  641 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  15769      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd       973            root    3u  IPv4  19516      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       973            root    4u  IPv6  19533      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      1388            root    3u  IPv4  21610      0t0  TCP 172.11.25.109:22->95.91.208.58:60491 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      1523          ubuntu    3u  IPv4  21610      0t0  TCP 172.11.25.109:22->95.91.208.58:60491 (ESTABLISHED)
node      1743            root   24u  IPv4  23414      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
nginx     1924            root    8u  IPv4  25687      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     1924            root    9u  IPv4  25688      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     1928        www-data    8u  IPv4  25687      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     1928        www-data    9u  IPv4  25688      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

I am able to see the website on **http://example.com** but I get an error when I try to go to **https://example.com**. I get the error -

```
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

How can I correctly host the web app on HTTPS?

Answer (score 3):

> So I redirected HTTP & HTTPS requests to port 3000 using  ...

This is directing IP packets to port 80 and 443 directly to port 3000, which means that nginx will completely be bypassed. Any configuration for nginx is thus irrelevant.

The access to `https://example.com` will try a TLS handshake on port 443 which is essentially port 3000 (because of the redirect of the IP packets) - but port 3000 does not understand TLS. The server on port 3000 will instead expect plain HTTP and return an HTTP error since the start of the TLS handshake obviously is no valid HTTP request. This error message then will be interpreted as the TLS response which causes this strange error message.

What you need to do instead of the iptables rules is to configure nginx as reverse proxy, see for example [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/use-nginx-reverse-proxy/) how to do this.